# How to use Python API of Stanford NER?

Tags: python, jar, nltk, stanford-nlp

## Version

- Windows 7
- Python 2.7.10
- NLTK 3.1
- Stanford NER 3.6 (2015-12-09)

## Issue

I trained a custom NER model with Stanford NER and got a serialized model. Then I tried using the model to carry out NER on unseen corpus via Python API provided by NLTK.

According to the [documentation](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#module-nltk.tag.stanford), I should specify the path to model and the path to `stanford-ner.jar`. However, I need to specify both the path to `stanford-ner.jar` and the path to `slf4j-api.jar` because the Stanford NER requires the logging module.

I could not figure out how to specify the two paths in the NLTK API. The constructor takes two arguments where the first one is `path/to/model` and the second one is `path/to/jar`. I tried concatenating two jar paths, putting them in a list and a tuple but none of the methods worked.

How can I tell NLTK to find both jars in order to invoke prediction?

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide any code you tried? By looking at the [source code from the nltk.tag.stanford module](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tag/stanford.html) it looks like you just have to initiate the StanfordNERTagger with the model and the path to the stanford-ner JAR, and the logger is added to the classpath automatically.

This is what the `__init__()` method from the StanfordTagger superclass does right after setting the model and the engine. It looks for the logger JAR inside the parent folder of the stanford-ner JAR path you provide and adds it to the path implicitly by calling `find_jars_within_path()` from `nltk.internals`, which under the hood is appending the folder to `os.path`